# Does algolia support Field Collapsing like Elasticsearch and Solr?

Tags: algolia

I currently use Algolia, I need Field Collapsing (like on [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html) and [Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)) for my use case, does algolia support it ?

I can find anything on it on Algolia website.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a grouping feature with algolia, it's called "distinct": https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/distinct#distinct-for-grouping

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for